# Check how many routines in header file math.h from the command line

Tags: shell

I could reference a particular routine from the command line with

```
man sqrt
```

or have a overview of all the routines from [math.h](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/math_h.htm)

Is it possible to retrieve a routine list of math.h from command line?

Alternatively tried,

```
$ man -s 3 -k math
matherr (3)          - SVID math library exception handling
```

but did not get results as expected.

Comment: This question seems to be more about manpages than it is about either of the two languages you have tagged.

Comment: Please tag this as shell scripting rather than C++....

Comment: `man math.h` might help. (Or possibly `man 7 math.h`, depending on your installation.)

Comment: I have removed the language tags that attract people seeking to answer questions about either C or C++, only to discover the question's lack of relevance to either, potentially comment about inappropriate tag use and be instructed to shut up.  With this change, there's less chance that you'll annoy people which means more chance someone will want to help you.

Comment: @Calculus : I don't have the `math.h` pages installed on my machine, but looking at the version posted [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/math.h.0p.html), it seems that the math functions mentioned there are lines ending in a semicolon. Hence having `grep` count the number of those lines might give you a quite accurate figure. I just wonder why someone might want to know this number .....

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math

Comment: Do a `find /usr/include -type f -name "*math*"` to find out what math include files you have on your system. Then examine their contents, and `grep` the appropriate file(s) for what you are looking for.

Comment: I think one reasonable approach would be to generate a file that contains `#include <math.h>` (and nothing else), and then run that through the preprocessor with an option (usually `-E` or `-P`) to capture the output.  You can then analyze that for the functions declared (and inline functions defined).  On a Mac running macOS (Mojave 10.14.6 — don't ask; it upsets me too), this yielded 224 functions in `<math.h>`.